# MySQL loads CPU with 300000 row operations reads/s

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Two days ago I moved my project (laravel 5.2) to a new server (ubuntu 16.04) and here MySQL loads: CPU from 20% to 96% (mostly ~60%)

After some googling I've found that I have huge amount of row operations reads while number of actual SQL requests is not high.

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
2017-10-05 09:24:13 0x7f2569d6c700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 3 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 68801 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 18248 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 87018
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 8428731
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1049415
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 10013240, OS waits 7717475
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 11622674, OS waits 596520
RW-sx spins 43, rounds 1144, OS waits 26
Spin rounds per wait: 10013240.00 RW-shared, 11622674.00 RW-excl, 26.60 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1192902
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1192898 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 64
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421274537903552, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421274537902632, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421274537900792, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421274537905392, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421274537899872, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
134319 OS file reads, 1022239 OS file writes, 541635 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 2.67 writes/s, 2.67 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 1841 merges
merged operations:
 insert 2765, delete mark 26, delete 1
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 105 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 25 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 188 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 31 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 543 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 739 buffer(s)
Hash table size 138401, node heap has 1108 buffer(s)
15989.34 hash searches/s, 5807.40 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 1689955382
Log flushed up to   1689955382
Pages flushed up to 1689800947
Last checkpoint at  1689800947
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
342078 log i/o's done, 2.67 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 549715968
Dictionary memory allocated 1371432
Buffer pool size   32768
Free buffers       11851
Database pages     18174
Old database pages 6688
Modified db pages  273
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1787928, not young 33591955
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 134140, created 8425, written 614586
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 18174, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[283]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=28719, Main thread ID=139799261079296, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 3884020, updated 105341, deleted 12368, read 10503316194
1.67 inserts/s, 0.67 updates/s, 0.33 deletes/s, 21966.68 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

I have tried increasing InnoDB buffer but it had no affect.

**UPDATE**
thx to ikurcubic i tried to log slow queries and here what i found

```
SET timestamp=1507210148;
select *, (select count(*) from `posts` where `posts`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id` and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null) as `posts_count`, (select count(*) from `users` inner join `group_user` on `users`.`id` = `group_user`.`user_id` where `group_user`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`) as `members_count` from `groups` where `id_deleted` = '0' and exists (select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = `groups`.`user_id` and (`country_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18') or `id` = '14215')) and (`id` in ('108', '109', '110', '125', '128', '138', '150', '151', '153', '180', '196', '236', '247', '531', '795') or `user_id` = '14215') order by `private_group` desc, `last_post` desc, `order` asc limit 15 offset 0;
# Time: 2017-10-05T13:29:12.117282Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   961
# Query_time: 1.784599  Lock_time: 0.000133 Rows_sent: 15  Rows_examined: 413449
SET timestamp=1507210152;
select *, (select count(*) from `posts` where `posts`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id` and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null) as `posts_count`, (select count(*) from `users` inner join `group_user` on `users`.`id` = `group_user`.`user_id` where `group_user`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`) as `members_count` from `groups` where `id_deleted` = '0' and exists (select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = `groups`.`user_id` and (`country_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18') or `id` = '2307')) and (`id` in ('108', '109', '110', '111', '119', '120', '125', '126', '128', '132', '135', '136', '138', '145', '150', '153', '155', '158', '169', '175', '176', '180', '184', '186', '196', '203', '206', '223', '247', '253', '303', '321', '489', '531', '593') or `user_id` = '2307') order by `private_group` desc, `last_post` desc, `order` asc limit 15 offset 0;
# Time: 2017-10-05T13:29:12.578493Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   966
# Query_time: 1.503847  Lock_time: 0.000112 Rows_sent: 15  Rows_examined: 413449
```

In controller it looks like this:

```
$groups = Group::whereIdDeleted(0)->with('admin')->withCount('posts')->withCount('members');
$groups = $groups->whereHas('admin', function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->whereIn('country_id', $request::get('country_id', $this->countries));
            $q->orWhere('id', $this->user->id);
});
$type = $request::get('type', 'default');
$member_groups = Group::whereIdDeleted(0)->WhereHas('members', function ($query){
    $query->whereId($this->user->id);
        })->pluck('id')->toArray();
$groups = $groups->where(function ($q) use ($member_groups){
                        $q->whereIn('id', $member_groups)
                            ->orWhere('user_id',$this->user->id)
                        ;
                    });
$groups = $groups
                        ->orderBy('private_group', $request::get('sort_by_private', 'ASC'))
                        ->orderBy('last_post', 'DESC')
                        ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
                        ->paginate($request::get('per_page', 15));
```

How can I optimize this request? In short it looks for groups that the user is administrating or member.

Comment: Now that I've seen larvel controller I'm sure there are index problems on mysql tables. One: Can you show migrations for these tables? Two: can you rewrite Eloquent code differently so Eloquent will not generate such a complex SQL query?

Comment: @GeorgeLiutovich Please post EXPLAIN SELECT ..... for the first query. Post results of SHOW INDEX FROM posts; - users - groups. We would then have an idea of available indexes and cardinality of data. SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '_size'; would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help. After some analyzing slow queries I found that withCount('members') on belongsToMany causes reading of all rows in users table (it generated count(*) from users where ...) and ->selectRaw('(select count(*) from `group_user` where `group_user`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`) as `members_count`') where I count rows from pivot table solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can enable [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) and check querys you run. I think some query does not use indexes, or maybe you have [lazy loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of records with Eloquent.

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN SELECT ..... for the first query.  Post results of SHOW INDEX FROM posts;  -  users  -  groups.  We would then have an idea of available indexes and cardinality of data.  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '_size';  would be helpful.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I think this is question for George Liutovich :)

Comment: You are correct.  Reposted for GeorgeL.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest running https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
Ideally on new server and old (if still got access) to spot the differences and see if anything needs optimising.